# Spring MVC Restful Application error 404. Why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, controller

I'm making a RESTful app without a View. Using PostMan, I make a test Get request, but I keep getting 404.

I put a breakpoint in the controller, but the request does not reach. I'm trying to make a service without a View and want to send and receive json requests in the future, but at this stage I need to check that requests reach the controllers. It doesn't work yet.

there are already a lot of questions and answers on STO, but unfortunately they are all made with a View.

**SpringConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ml.antanaks.school.concert")
public class SpringConfig {
}
```

**SpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer.java**

```
public class SpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

**console**

```
/Users//Documents/apache-tomcat-10.0.5/bin/catalina.sh run
[2021-04-21 01:02:18,072] Artifact natalyalearn:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.562 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.5
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.564 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 30 2021 08:19:50 UTC
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.575 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.0.5.0
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.575 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.575 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Версия ОС:             10.15.7
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.575 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Архитектура:           x86_64
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.576 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Users/user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_282/Contents/Home/jre
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.576 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Версия JVM:            1.8.0_282-b08
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.576 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Amazon.com Inc.
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.576 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/user/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/tomcat/48517f15-6cdb-422a-a021-e59ff424c802
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/user/Documents/apache-tomcat-10.0.5
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.583 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/user/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/tomcat/48517f15-6cdb-422a-a021-e59ff424c802/conf/logging.properties
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.589 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.589 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.590 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.590 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.593 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/Users/user/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/tomcat/48517f15-6cdb-422a-a021-e59ff424c802/jmxremote.password
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.594 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/Users/user/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/tomcat/48517f15-6cdb-422a-a021-e59ff424c802/jmxremote.access
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.595 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.596 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.596 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/user/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/tomcat/48517f15-6cdb-422a-a021-e59ff424c802
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.596 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/user/Documents/apache-tomcat-10.0.5
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/user/Documents/apache-tomcat-10.0.5/temp
21-Apr-2021 01:02:20.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/user/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
21-Apr-2021 01:02:21.879 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
21-Apr-2021 01:02:21.931 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [2533] milliseconds
21-Apr-2021 01:02:22.123 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
21-Apr-2021 01:02:22.124 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.5]
21-Apr-2021 01:02:22.151 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
21-Apr-2021 01:02:22.318 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [386] milliseconds
Connected to server
[2021-04-21 01:02:22,694] Artifact natalyalearn:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
21-Apr-2021 01:02:30.127 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2021-04-21 01:02:30,231] Artifact natalyalearn:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2021-04-21 01:02:30,232] Artifact natalyalearn:war exploded: Deploy took 7,538 milliseconds
21-Apr-2021 01:02:32.162 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Installing a web application in a folder [/Users/user/Documents/apache-tomcat-10.0.5/webapps/manager]
21-Apr-2021 01:02:32.234 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Users/user/Documents/apache-tomcat-10.0.5/webapps/manager] has finished in [72] ms
```

Comment: What end-point you are making GET request from? `http://server:port/hello` ? Or `http://server:port/user/hello` ? Check for typos too. This is most common mistake most people make.

Comment: @AjayKumar yes, I checked the correctness of the input in the first place. I write http://localhost:8080/user/hello

Comment: can you put your console output here?

Comment: @AjayKumar Yes, of course. I added data from the console to the post.

Comment: Look into what port it is you have configured in tomcat/spring.

Comment: @Susan Mustafa In the console I see 8080

Comment: Are your all classes/interfaces in the same package or different packages? If different packages, make sure you include all of them in your component scan.

Comment: TL;DR: Spring requires a Java EE servlet container, Tomcat 10 is a Jakarta EE servlet container.

Comment: All classes are in the same package. Which I specified in @ComponentScan

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz  I use TomCat ver10. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't using Spring Boot, which is the modern way to build Spring applications?

Comment: @IlyaY: Yes, Spring does not work on Tomcat 10. Downgrade to Tomcat 9.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Yes thank you. It worked. Can you add your answer so I can mark it as the best one?

Comment: Thanks, but I believe your question is just a (nicely redacted) duplicate of the aforementioned question (or similar questions) and should be closed.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz ok) i closed a question